# Partial Orders on finite sets to which Zorn's lemma does not apply

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Zorn's lemma is stated in the text I'm reading as

> If $(A, \leq)$ is a poset such that every chain of elements in $A$ has an upper bound in $A$, then $A$ has at least one maximal element.

However, I can't think of any partial ordering (defined as a relation which is reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive) on which the condition

> If $(A, \leq)$ is a poset such that every chain of elements in $A$ has an upper bound in $A$

would not hold if $A$ is a finite set. (I understand how an infinite set like $[0, 1)$ would fail to satisfy this requirement). My argument is that if $C$ is a chain in the poset $(A, \leq)$ then there will be an end to the chain which will be an element in the chain, and hence every set will satisfy this.

Then can we say that if $A$ is a finite set then any poset $(A, \leq)$ has at least one maximal element by Zorn's lemma? If not, is there a counter-example to help me understand?

Comment: You can say so, but it looks like Zorn's lemma is overkill. You can just compare all elements to each other, which is a finite process due to the finiteness of $A$. and does not use the Axiom of choice.

Comment: @max_zorn you mean zorn's lemma is useful in contexts other than the ones which deal with finite sets? Also, even though you say "you can just compare all elements to each other which is a finite process", you are assuming that there exists a maximal element in any poset on a finite $A$. Is this true?

Comment: 1) The big use of Zorn's lemma is exactly for infinite sets. You can prove things like every vector space has a Hamel basis, which is amazing since nobody knows one in, say, the space of all sequences. 2) I don't assume there is a maximal element, this is a consequence of just comparing all elements in the finite $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there is a counterexample, but it's not a very interesting one: if $A=\emptyset$, then the empty chain has no upper bound.  However, any nonempty finite poset satisfies the conditions of Zorn's lemma.  Indeed, any finite nonempty chain has a greatest element (this is easy to prove by induction on the size of the chain), which is then an upper bound.  (And as long as $A$ is nonempty, the empty chain also has an upper bound, namely any element of $A$.)

As others have mentioned, Zorn's lemma is kind of overkill for finite posets, because you can prove they have maximal elements without the axiom of choice.  However, I think they are actually an instructive example for understanding the proof of Zorn's lemma in general.  There is an obvious way to find a maximal element of a (nonempty) finite poset: start with one chosen element, and then compare it with all the elements of the poset one by one, changing your chosen element whenever you find another element that is greater than it.  This argument is in fact exactly how you prove Zorn's lemma in the general case as well, except that you need to choose a well-ordering of the poset and use it to go through the elements one-by-one by transfinite induction, and at limit steps you need to use the hypothesis that chains have upper bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote , many years ago , an example that may satisfy your curiosity:

https://coldoc.sns.it/UUID/EDB/02M/?lang=en_US

Indeed in this example there is a partial order that cannot satisfy Zorn's Lemma hypotheses, but it is not obvious at first sight.